# Find out address of opened popup in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, reverse-engineering

A third party website (vSphere Client if anyone's interested) has a button that opens a new tab. The opened tab has a special protocol that is supposed to be handled by an external application (`vmrc://` in this case). Unfortunately, Chrome just displays `about:blank` in the address bar.

[image: new tab with about:blank address bar, and a dialogue to open the special vmrc-link with another application]

How do I find out what address my external application (VMware Remote Console in this case) will receive? Chrome's network inspector does not show anything. Is there maybe a way to intercept the `window.open` call when the tab is being opened?

Comment: Have you tried retracing the operations from the Html downward? (hove above the button action and follow the beradcrums untill th eurl is constructed)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround by creating my own external application that just writes the link to a log file. Here it is in python:

```py
from sys import argv
from pathlib import Path

with open(Path.home() / 'argumentgrabber.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write('\n'.join(argv))
```

I compiled this to an exe with `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`. Now in the new tab I can just choose to 'select another application' and open the mistery link with my python script.